# jquery toggle triggers twice on child element?

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a div (id="menu") on my page with onclick="toggledropdown()". This div has child img elements as well as text. The toggle code works just fine when anything but the images is clicked. However, when the images are clicked, the div slides down and then back up again.

toggle code:

```
function toggledropdown()
{
    if ($("#dropdown").is(":hidden"))
    {   
        $("#dropdown").slideDown(400);      
    }
    else
    {
        $("#dropdown").slideUp(50);     
    }
}
```

body.click to hide drop down if the page is clicked:

```
$(document.body).click(function(event)
{
    var targetID = $(event.target).attr("id");
    if (targetID !== "dropdown" && targetID !== "menu")
    {
        if (!$("#dropdown").is(":hidden"))
            toggledropdown();
    }
});
```

drop down.click to negate the body.click

```
$("#dropdown").click(function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The html div (some things unrelated to problem omitted):

```
<div class="menu" id="menu" onclick="toggledropdown();">
    <img id="dropdownthumbnail" (blahsrc/styleblah) />
    Text
    <img id="dropdownarrow" (blahsrc/styleblah) />
</div>
```

So, to reiterate, clicking on the menu div (minus the images) slides out the menu correctly, clicking on it again (including the images) or anywhere else on the page works correctly, but clicking on the images while the drop down is hidden toggles it twice (you can see it slide out and back in again).

Are the child imgs triggering the parent's onclick twice? Once for the child, once for the parent? Why? How do I make it work as expected: clicking anywhere on the div triggers the onclick once?

Comment: event.stopPropagation() is what you need http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: What's the `$("#dropdown")` element in your code? Also, why are you using inline JavaScript?

Comment: Are you clicking the image before the slide animation is complete? If yes, try using `$("#dropdown").stop(true, true).slideDown(400);` and `$("#dropdown").stop(true, true).slideDown(400);`? Also get rid of the inline script and move it to the handler code.

Comment: @wirey $("#dropdownarrow").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();}); causes it to not call the toggle at all.

Comment: @Vega No, if clicked once, the #dropdown slides down and then up again. And I got rid of the in-line javascript. Didn't fix anything, but thanks for getting on my case about standard practices.

Comment: @j08691 #dropdown is the new div that appears when #menu is clicked on. Nothing special in it, just some links. And I don't know why I used inline javascript, I'm just silly. Been replaced. Didn't fix it.

Comment: @wirey I figured I needed a stopPropagation() somewhere, just didn't know where. Turns out putting it in the onclick for the #menu div with the imgs along with the toggledropdown() worked. Put that info in an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to stop events from bubbling up.

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Which will prevent parent handlers from firing their events

Comment: Yup. Specifically, in the click binding for the #menu above the toggledropdown() call. Like so:
    $("#menu").click(function(e)
    {
     e.stopPropagation();
     toggledropdown();
    });