# jquery toggle visibility on first click

Tags: jquery

I am having some strange problems with jquery toggle() visibility, on the first click to element it throws 2 times..
This is the code

```
function handleSearchToggle() {
  $(prestashop.themeSelectors.header.searchToggle).off('click');
  $(prestashop.themeSelectors.header.searchToggle).on("click", function(e) {
    $(prestashop.themeSelectors.header.searchBox).toggle();
    console.log('stop');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}

$(() => {
  handleSearchToggle();
});
```

Problem can be show here [naturaval.com](https://naturaval.com)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery toggle triggers twice on child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465459/jquery-toggle-triggers-twice-on-child-element)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by replacing e.preventDefault() with e.stopPropagation();